# Whats the difference bewteen a GSLB and ADC(application delivery controller)

Tags: networking, load-balancing, gslb

Whats the difference bewteen a GSLB and ADC. I can see that both can do load balancing, but i want to know the difference and additional functionalities each can perform. And i'd also want to know if one can replace the other.

Answer (score 1):

- GSLB is a general Term: Global Server Load Balancing
- ADC is a Citrix product which does GSLB as well as proxying traffic.

To replace an ADC deployment, which saves f**king money(man they charge lots for it),
the proxy part can be replaced with NGINX + Server, the GSLB(which is just DNS with healthchecks) can be replaced with BIND(which actually runs on ADC as a service) and healthckeck to the backend server to remove/add record to DNS.